# How to make MySQL query run as fast as possible?

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query to get value and check condition from two tables. Fuel(timestamp,fuellevel,address) and DrivingTime(starttime,stoptime). I want to show all fields in Fuel table base on the condition `timestamp = starttime` or `timestamp = stoptime`. The query run correctly, but very slow. I expected it run faster but I confused of how to do it. This is my query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(F.timestamp), 
       F.fuellevel, 
       F.address 
FROM   gtse.tblfuel F, 
       gtse.tbldrivingtime DT 
WHERE  ( DT.starttime = F.timestamp 
          OR DT.stoptime = F.timestamp ) 
       AND ( FROM_UNIXTIME(DT.starttime) BETWEEN 
                 '2014-04-01 00:00:41' AND '2014-04-10 23:22:39' ) 
       AND F.accountid = 'vinhnghia' 
       AND F.deviceid = '14C-00262' 
       AND F.accountid = DT.accountid 
ORDER  BY F.timestamp;
```

Can someone give some idea?

Comment: post EXPLAIN... and put indexes on your PK's... and drop the old pre ansi way of joining tables... sigh...

Comment: You may want to use an actual join there. Also, do you have your indices and keys set?

Comment: Agree, use explicit joins and index any fields you are going to do heavy querying on. I would also suggest (only as a means of removing unnecessary calls on your data return) offloading the from_unixtime() call on each of the records, and perform that in your business/display layer.

Comment: FWIW, old SQL-89 join syntax (comma-style) and SQL-92 join syntax (with the `JOIN` keyword) optimize exactly the same in most RDBMS implementations. There is no *performance* reason to use one over the other.

Comment: @DinhNgocHien, if you ask a question about query optimization, you should include information about the table design and current optimizer plan. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE gtse.tblfuel` and likewise for the second table, and include this in your question. Also, run `EXPLAIN` followed by your query, and include that information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT F.deviceID,
        F.timestamp, 
        F.address, F.fuelLevel
 FROM gtse.tblFuel F 
 INNER JOIN gtse.tblDrivingTime DT 
 ON F.accountID=DT.accountID 
      and F.deviceID=DT.deviceID 
      and (DT.startTime = F.timestamp or DT.stopTime = F.timestamp)
 where (DT.`startTime` BETWEEN  1412874000 and 1413306000 ) 
      and F.accountID = 'vinhnghia' and F.deviceID = '14C-00262' 
      order by F.`timestamp` desc;
```

Please send me feedback if you still get stuck with your problem.

Comment: I tried your code and it is better than the original code, thank you.

Comment: you are welcome here, please try to make your question clearer and give more information that are relevant to your problem, it is better for supporters